# count number of string occurence from output MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

```
diary_file = tempname();
diary(diary_file);         
myFun(); 
diary('off');             
output = fileread(diary_file);

strToSearch = 'variable failed'
```

Is there a known function to count occurence of a string from the output file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html):

```
>>output = 'this sentence is a test sentence';
>>strToSearch = 'sentence';
>>numel(strfind(output,strToSearch))
ans =
     2
```

`strfind` tells you the starting indices where the sought string (`strToSearch`) is located within the text (`output`); and `numel` tells you how many such indices there are.